# Write data column from one file to many files using R

Tags: r

Hello I wwould like to group data based on the column name and write them into different files using R.Like the below table:

```
    x_B289_blank    x_B291_blank    m_B301_blank    o_B291_blank    m_B289_blank
aa  0   3   0   0   0
as  0   0   0   0   0
ac  16  0   0   0   0
ad  0   0   0   0   0
aq  0   0   0   0   0
ac  0   0   0   0   0
```

I would like to make same column name data in the same file with row name.

Comment: Is that a table or data-frame? and please fix the formatting.

Comment: show us first several lines of your data.frame using `head(variable)`.

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear.  Are you saying that you want each column to be written to a separate file?

Answer (score 0):

```
 filenams <- names(dfrm)
 for (i in 1:length(filenams) ) { write.table(dfrm[ , i], file=filenams[i]) }
```